# Missing cache file error when creating Azure Cloud package using cspack.exe

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am getting missing file error when I am creating Azure Cloud package using cspack.exe

[Full Size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ar4.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not a cspack expert, but I don't think including the file in startup sequence of csdef makes it include the file in the solution.

Can you check your project that the perf counter installer is included ?

Comment: I can see that both service file and that folder exist at same level after build. even this exe file exist inside folder

Comment: Definitely mentioning a file in csdef has no influence on cspack. The file should be added to the role payload project and appropriate "build action" should be specified for it.